# sim800l ftp error after http request

Tags: arduino-uno, esp32, sim800

I am using esp32 CAM by Arduino IDE and send an image file by ftp using SIM800l GSM/GPRS  module  to a server and every thing is ok .
I can perform http request also and read some data from a website and every thing is ok.

Problem is ftp for large file  and http request can not work at the same time .
if I send AT+HTTPINIT after AT+FTPEXTPUT=1 , it fails
or if I send AT+FTPEXTPUT=1  after  AT+HTTPINIT again it fails .

I close http connection by AT+SAPBR=0,1 but problem exist

How to solve this problem?
How is possible to clear the setting done in the  the sim800l without restarting the module by AT+CFUN=1,1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way to solve the problem .
Http request must be terminated with command AT+HTTPTERM . After this command large ftp works and command AT+FTPEXTPUT=1 is without error . After termination of ftp if we want to do http request again the command AT+FTPEXTPUT=0 must be executed